How to add a column/attribute dynamically by clicking a button in MS Dynamics 365?
I've created a Ribbon Workbench button and added an action of JavaScript to create a string attribute('resource_name') in the Opportunity Table. But, when I click on the button nothing happens, it neither shows success nor failure.
Need your expert advice on whether to change the script or to go with another approach. Please share a way to create new attributes dynamically at the click of a button. Dynamics 365/PowerApps
Javascript Used -
function addDemoAttribute() {
    var entityName = "opportunity";
    var attributeName = "resuource_name";
    var attributeDisplayName = "Resource Name";
    var maxLength = 100;
    var description = "A demo attribute integration";
    var attributeMetadata = {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StringAttributeMetadata",
        "LogicalName": attributeName,
        "DisplayName": {
            "LocalizedLabels": [
                {
                    "Label": attributeDisplayName,
                    "LanguageCode": 1033
                }
            ]
        },
        "MaxLength": maxLength,
        "RequiredLevel": {
            "Value": "None"
        },
        "Description": {
            "LocalizedLabels": [
                {
                    "Label": description,
                    "LanguageCode": 1033
                }
            ]
        },
        "SchemaName": attributeName
    };
    var request = {
        entity: {
            logicalName: entityName
        },
        MetadataId: null,
        AttributeType: 'String',
        Attribute: attributeMetadata
    };
    Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(request).then(
        function success(result) {
            if (result.ok) {
                Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog({ text: "Attribute created successfully." });
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            Xrm.Navigation.openErrorDialog({ message: "Error creating attribute: " + error.message });
        }
    );
}

I tried JS code mentioned above. It will be really helpful if someone can guide me with a better approach to add attributes dynamically in Tables/Entities in MS Dynamics.

to do this you can call a HTTP POST Url and pass the payload. to call this URL you can use JS function or a workflow (i used workflow).
this is the payload to hit and the URL
URL:https://<ORGANIZATION-URL>/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='<ENTITY-NAME>')/Attributes
Payload:
{
  "SchemaName": "new_fieldname",
  "LogicalName": "new_fieldname",
  "DisplayName": {
    "LocalizedLabels": [
      {
        "Label": "New Field Title",
        "LanguageCode": 1033,
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel"
      }
    ],
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label"
  },
  "RequiredLevel": {
    "Value": "None",
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty"
  },
  "MaxLength": 100,
  "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StringAttributeMetadata"
}

My Test result:
I used postman to trigger my workflow where i dynamically pass the field name, entity name, schema name and datatype

Once triggered, the flow composes the body and hits the URL.

as a result, the table is created dynamically.


Thanks @Laviza, this really helped :)
